# db2 pagination query performance

Tags: performance, pagination, db2

I´m doing a paginated query using the following template:

```
select * from (select rownumber() over
( order by aaa.x ) as rownum,  aaa.abc, aaa.bcd,bbb.cde from aaa as aaa 
left join bbb on aaa.colx= bbb.coly where aaa.where1 = 'xxx'
) as tempresult where rownum between 101 and 200
```

Assuming a page size of 100 items, the first page query would be the same thing, replacing the rownum condition for:

```
where rownum <= 100
```

I´m facing a situation where the first page performs very well ( <1s ), but when we move from the second page-forward the query takes about 5-6s.

1. Can anyone explain me why is that the case?
2. Is there any way to slight modify this query template in order to achieve better performance?
3. Is there any complete different strategy that could perform better?

Additional Info:

- I use DB2 v9.7.400.501
- There´s no limit keyword
- I cannot create views or stored procedures due to a customer constraint
- I cannot create any additional indexes
- Tried switching from rownumber() no rank() but it didnt change anything

Answer (score 2):

You will need to look at both queries' execution plans to see if there is any difference -- only that can give you a definite answer.

You could try rewriting the query like so:

```
select * from (
  select rownumber() over ( order by aaa.x ) as rownum,  aaa.abc, aaa.bcd 
  from aaa as aaa 
  where aaa.where1 = 'xxx'
) as tempresult 
left join bbb on tempresult.colx= bbb.coly 
and tempresult.rownum between 101 and 200
```

**Edit:**

Nothing prevents you from using columns from `bbb` in the final select:

```
select tempresult.*, bbb.cde 
from (
  select rownumber() over ( order by aaa.x ) as rownum,  aaa.abc, aaa.bcd 
  from aaa as aaa 
  where aaa.where1 = 'xxx'
) as tempresult 
left join bbb on tempresult.colx= bbb.coly 
and tempresult.rownum between 101 and 200
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer Mustaccio. Actually, removing entirely the left join made it perform really fast! But, I couldn´t move the join as u said since there was actually a bbb.cde inside the original query (edited question).

Comment: actually, I managed it to work on your line by modifying the query further. I just don´t know, however, if I´ll be able to modify the code to generate the query like that, but anyway, it´s a really good tip. Thanks

Comment: yes, I did ur edit suggestion, but:

1) that would be a high costly modification on the code to regenerate those queries
2) if I needed to sort by the bbb.coly then I´d still need that thing inside of the rownumber() query (ok, I didn´t mentioned sorting capability, but will edit the question)